# HOW TO printf/sscanf 64 bit numbers in PURE C++98

Tags: c++, xcode

First, please excuse the question if it is somehow already answered. I looked and looked and never found something that would run in GNUC++ 4.2 WITHOUT extensions.

I need to printf and get input (sscanf) for 64 bit values using only C++ standards (no GNU extensions). I know about %I64d for MS compilers, and %lld for GNU, but those are not allowed in pure C++98 mode. PRId64 seems to be not allowed either. You get an invalid extension error in -pedantic for any of these format codes (Werror=format). I am trying to help someone port 100% working C89 code to Apple XCode for PowerPC (yes, old, but needs to run on old world Mac). This compiler is based on GCC4.2 and is supposed to comply with C99, but in C++98 mode you can't do 'long long' and he must program in C++, not C.  The original ancient code uses two tiny snippits of x86 asm to get the 64 bits in and out of 2 32 bit numbers into a 64 bit register, but I am hopeful in this day and age something a little more modern can be done.

I coded him something to emulate the x86 asm, but it is gross to say the least.  We looked and looked for some include file that would make this simple, but no combo works when tried on XCode, a real PC running old Watcom DOS C compiler (C89+64 bit _int64 extension), and a Visual Studio Express (don't recall version). These are all targets of the ported program.

Is it a huge mass if #ifdefs to make this work? Other programs seem to brew up a storm of #if _MSC_VER and #if MINGW32 and #if *GNUC* etc, etc:(

I'm not great at C++ myself, but I thought cin and cout would do all this for you if you get a 'native' 64 bit type?!?!?!

Sorry to run on at the mouth, but I'm trying to get as much info as possible in this question.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: is %lld a GNU extension?

Comment: @user3528438 `%lld` works with `__int64` in MSVC.

Comment: If it were possible without extensions, why would the extensions exist?

Comment: If it is C++ code why don't you use `cout`?

Comment: Pure C++98 doesn't even _have_ 64 bit values, so why do you think there should be a way to print them?